# System.TypeInitializationException in C# service when trying to install

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, service

The program builds and runs fine in Debug mode.  I can install it manually using vs command prompt installutil, but when I publish the program and attempt to install it on a different machine using setup.exe, I get this error and not sure why.

What kind of things should I be looking for that would cause System.TypeInitializationException?  What scenarios would cause this exception?

Let me clarify a little further.  I didn't write the program, this is a project I've been handed, so I'm not sure where to look for this type of exception.  The installer.cs files doesn't have any static variables or constructors.  Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: Some type initializing is failing. So look at the type initializing methods (`static MyType {}`) for possible pitfalls...

Comment: I've previously had issues with a wrong version of InstallUtil.exe being chosen by install scripts - unfortunately I don't remember the exact errors given. Could you find out which one the setup file is using/try a manual install with "%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\<your framework>\<your framework version>\InstallUtil.exe"

Answer (score 1):

This means that a type could not be initialized because an exception is occurring either in a static initializer or static constructor.

```
class MyClass
{
    static Monkey monkey = new ThrowingErrorMonkey(); //here
    static MyClass()
    {
        throw new Exception(); //or here
    }
}
```

Comment: Might try using a remote debugger to step through the code and see where the exception is being thrown inside one of these ctor/init

Comment: Let me clarify, I'm not sure why the exception is happening because I didn't write the program.  It was a project I was handed.  The installer.cs file doesn't have any static variables or constructors.